# VOLTTRON startup failed/timed out

Tags: python, volttron

I am attempting to get Volttron configured on a rasp pi B+

This appears to install Ok:
`./scripts/rabbit_dependencies.sh raspbian buster`
 `python3 bootstrap.py --drivers --force`

But trying to start the Volttron service I am having some issues:

```
(volttron) pi@raspberrypi:~/volttron $ ./start-volttron
Starting VOLTTRON verbosely in the background with VOLTTRON_HOME=/home/pi/.volttron
Waiting for VOLTTRON to startup..
VOLTTRON startup failed/timed out. Please check volttron.log for details
```

Any tips going through the commands for the bootstrap process greatly appreciated on Just installing all drivers.

Errors:

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
Missing library jwt within web package.
2020-11-23 19:10:46,345 () volttron.platform.agent.utils DEBUG: value from env None
2020-11-23 19:10:46,347 () volttron.platform.agent.utils DEBUG: value from config False
```

Errors:

```
(volttron) pi@raspberrypi:~/volttron $ vcfg
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenle                                                                                                            t size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header,                                                                                                             got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenle                                                                                                            t size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header,                                                                                                             got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenle                                                                                                            t size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header,                                                                                                             got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenle                                                                                                            t size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header,                                                                                                             got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenle                                                                                                            t size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header,                                                                                                             got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenle                                                                                                            t size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header,                                                                                                             got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenle                                                                                                            t size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header,                                                                                                             got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenle                                                                                                            t size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header,                                                                                                             got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenle                                                                                                            t size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header,                                                                                                             got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenle                                                                                                            t size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header,                                                                                                             got 76 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)

Your VOLTTRON_HOME currently set to: /home/pi/.volttron

Is this the volttron you are attempting to setup? [Y]:
What type of message bus (rmq/zmq)? [zmq]:
What is the vip address? [tcp://127.0.0.1]:
What is the port for the vip address? [22916]:
Is this instance web enabled? [N]:
Will this instance be controlled by volttron central? [Y]:
Segmentation fault
(volttron) pi@raspberrypi:~/volttron $ Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

***EDIT***

`git cloned Version/7.x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain that I've seen exactly this, but I think I've seen something similar where there are error about incompatible c libraries. I believe that previously we saw that when someone was trying to run raspbian on an x86 system, and possibly also when trying to resolve erlang and RMQ dependencies on on raspbian 9. Could you clarify a few things:

- Is this a newly flashed raspbian image, or older (that is, could there be older installed package versions running, or is everything new; also has this system ever successfully run any version of volttron?)
- Are you trying to run with RMQ or ZMQ? It appears that you've tried to install dependencies for RMQ, but configured the platform for ZMQ. Either should work, but would like to minimize the number of things we're tweaking.
- Could you post a `pip freeze` of the venv you're working with so we can see the exact set of package versiosn?

If you're on the volttron community slack, we can try and debug more real-time there (and try to remember to come back and note the answer here once we've found it).

Comment: Hi Ben, ill to pip freeze and flash the rasb pi to a new image. Its fairly new but not completely fresh. And also try to get on the Volttron community slack channel too.

Comment: Hi Ben, any chance you could give me a tip on this SO post for VOLTTRON? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077562/volttron-read-bacnet-points-to-message-bus

Comment: Um, James is certainly much more experienced than I am with BACnet and the driver framework generally. In your original post you ask about logs, that should certainly be possible over ssh in the same way as if you were using a local terminal with directly attached keyboard and monitor. By default you'd tail the file volttron.log in the VOLTTRON_ROOT directory (next to start-volttron), though it is also possible to configure other paths.