# bacnet_scan output a csv file error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, volttron

When running bacnet_scan.py it looks like this:

```
(volttron) (base) bartlino@bartlino-Latitude-E5530-non-vPro:~/Desktop/volttron/scripts/bacnet$ python bacnet_scan.py

Device Address        = <Address 192.168.0.190>
Device Id             = 0
maxAPDULengthAccepted = 1476
segmentationSupported = noSegmentation
vendorID              = 245

Device Address        = <Address 192.168.0.102>
Device Id             = 3056183
maxAPDULengthAccepted = 1024
segmentationSupported = segmentedBoth
vendorID              = 842

Device Address        = <RemoteStation 12345:2>
Device Id             = 201201
maxAPDULengthAccepted = 286
segmentationSupported = noSegmentation
vendorID              = 11
```

Trying to add on a csv file output with `python bacnet_scan.py --csv-out ~/Desktop/volttron/configs/test_mult.csv`

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bacnet_scan.py", line 203, in <module>
    this_csv_file.writeheader()
  File "/home/bartlino/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/csv.py", line 143, in writeheader
    return self.writerow(header)
  File "/home/bartlino/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not working out of the latest development branch, I'd suggest trying that first, as there was a [PR accepted after the 8.0 release](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blame/develop/scripts/bacnet/bacnet_scan.py#L196) that fixed an issue related to bytes vs string in the output of this script.  I'm also not certain how they'd interact, but you appear to have 2 virtual environments activated currently, and its possible that's messing with some versioning... Since its Python3.8 for your Anaconda, I'm doubtful of that, but its something to consider.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: would you have any tips for not using two virtual environments? Im not sure how that happened. Before I start volttron I only do one `source env/bin/activate`

Comment: The second one as above is the (ana)conda base environment.  Conda will activate the base when the user logs in.   [Here's some information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default) about that situation.  In summary, use this: `conda config --set auto_activate_base false`